# how to find accuracy and f_measure from confusion matrix using matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have used the following function for finding confusion matrix c=confusionmat(x,y)
it gives me output like that ,

C =

```
 0     4     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     4     0
```

now i want to find accuracy and f_measure from this confusion matrix

Comment: What have you tried to find those quantities and what problem are you facing?

Comment: If the accuracy is 100% then only the diagonal of your matrix will contain non-zero value. So you can simply compare how many value are in the diagonal vs the whole matrice.